# Grammaticality of 'Closed on eve of and public holidays'

Tags: grammaticality

I saw a sign that read

> Closed on eve of and public holidays (1)

which obviously meant

> Closed on eve of public holidays and public holidays (2)

This made me wonder if (1) is grammatical. If not, what is a nice way of expressing the intended idea that is shorter than (2)?

Comment: Closed on the eve of, and on, public holidays.

Comment: It's a sign. They don't have to be grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

I would distribute the "on" to both sides of "and", when expanding.  As such, it would expand as:

> Closed on eve of public holidays and on public holidays.

...which is perfectly grammatical.

I won't argue that the initial construct isn't annoying, though.  It might better be worded:

> Closed on public holidays and the eve thereof.

But, clear as that is, it sounds a bit hoidy-toidy.  Maybe this:

> Closed on public holidays and the day before.

I don't know.

It might be easier to just be specific as the holiday is approaching:

> Closed Christmas eve.  Re-opening Boxing Day.

Answer (score 0):

**Closed on eve of and during public holidays.**

As in:

[Interfax-Ukraine](https://en.interfax.com.ua/news/general/553148.html)

> Russian forces have been arranging provocations to be staged on the
>   **eve of and during** the Unification Assembly of the Orthodox Church in
>   Ukraine that is scheduled for December 15 in Kyiv.